# How do I run the SWT Win32 extension example program locally?

Tags: winapi, swt

I am looking into using the [SWT Win32 Extension](http://feeling.sourceforge.net/). I downloaded the [extension jar files](http://feeling.sourceforge.net/downloads/org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.zip), and the [example code](http://feeling.sourceforge.net/downloads/org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.example.zip). However, I couldn't find how to run the example. When I run the application with their [jnlp file](http://feeling.sourceforge.net/jws/example.jnlp),  it runs. When I looked into the file, I saw that they specify their main class as `org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.example.Example`, but this class is not part of the sample code (although almost everything else is, including the "about" dialog.

So what I'm looking for is either:

1. A simple main class code to run the example - or -
2. an explanation where I can get the original code for Example.java.

---

UPDATE:

Yay, it works. Thanks, @TrueSoft!

But just to clear a few points:

1. the source files to use come from org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.zip, right under the src folder. That one includes the org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.example.Example file I was missing in the first place
2. the 4 jar files in that zip under the lib folder are required for compilation
3. not one but 3 dll files (in that same lib folder) required for running
4. dll file path should be specified as a VM argument:

`-Djava.library.path="{containing folder path}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the sources both in the file [org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.example.zip](http://feeling.sourceforge.net/downloads/org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.example.zip) and in [org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.zip](http://feeling.sourceforge.net/downloads/org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.zip) (in /src directory).
To run the examples, you must add a user library with the file `org.sf.feeling.swt.win32.extension.jar` and include the file `swt-extension-win32.dll` in your project folder.

Comment: wow, talk about a late answer. Thanks! I'll have a look at it soon to see if it helps.

Comment: can I capture user activity by using this. For example, which application did user opened, how much time did user spent in different applications, what did user browsed, which are the productive tasks that user is spending time.